# LibreOffice, same dots (spacing) for all headings in index table

Tags: libreoffice

I'm using `LibreOffice 7.2.6.2` and while creating the index table in libreoffice writer, it creates the index with different dots sizes? for for heading.

[image]

how to have the same spacing for all heading ?

Comment: Isn't it that normal? Different levels of headings result also in different styles in TOC. You may need to at least make font (size, boldness, etc.) the _same_ for all these TOC styles, if you want them to be displayed identically.

Comment: @Fedcad, one can customize that in LO. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is consistent with the fact you are using different font sizes (and perhaps different fonts) for the sublevels.

It is possible to define the style of text at the levels of the individual elements on a line using character styles. On the "entries" tab of the "Table of Contents, Index or Bibliography" dialog, you can select individual elements and assign a specific character style to them. This way, you can make the dots adhere to the same character style.

For example, in the image below, a custom made character style, "Tab bullets", was applied to the <kbd>T</kbd> item, which stands for the Tap stop. Despite of the much bigger font for "Title 1", the dots appear the same for all levels.

[image]

Comment: Nice to know. :)